# How to make hover unique for `v-for` list item?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

I have a list element I loop through several times:

```
<template>
  <ul id='movieSearchResultList'>
    <li
      v-for='movie in searchList'
      v-on:mouseover='hoverEvent'
      v-on:mouseout='hoverEvent'
      :key='movie.id'>
      <AddMovieToDashboard v-if='hover' />
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

And a `hoverEvent` that toggles a `hover` attribute to true/false:

```
export default class MovieSearchResultList extends Vue {
  private hover = false;

  public hoverEvent() {
    this.hover = !this.hover;
  }

  get searchList(): Movie[] {
    return MovieSearchListStore.state.searchList;
  }
}
```

When I hover over a list element each element will display the `AddMovieToDashboard` component, but I only want to display it on the actively hovered list element.

Answer (score 4):

Updated the for to include the index:

```
v-for='(movie, index) in searchList'
```

Then pass the index on the mouseOver:

```
v-on:mouseover='hoverEvent(index)'
v-on:mouseleave='hoverEvent(null)'

public hover = -1;

public hoverEvent(index: number) {
  this.hover = index;
}
```

And finally check if index is the same as hover:

```
<AddMovieToDashboard v-if='hover === index' />
```

Comment: Nice and simple but I'd be more inclined to use the `movie.id` as the indicator rather than `index`. This would be especially important if you ever sorted your list

Comment: Just replace `hoverEvent(index)` with `hoverEvent(movie.id)`

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind...

1. Just use CSS.

   ```css
   #movieSearchResultList li div { /*  guessing your AddMovieToDashboard creates a div */
     display: none;
   }
   #movieSearchResultList li:hover div {
     display: block;
   }
   ```

   This would work more like `v-show` so if that's a problem, move on to...
2. Create a component for your list items to encapsulate functionality

   ```html
   <ul id="movieSearchResultList">
     <MovieSearchResult v-for="movie in searchList" :movie="movie" :key="movie.id" />
   </ul>
   ```

   with `MovieSearchResult` having the `<li>` and `mouseover` / `mouseout` logic